# How to add an image for Twitter cards on with posts with Jekyll-seo-tag?

Tags: image, twitter, jekyll, meta, twitter-card

Using Jekyll with Github Pages, when I share a post on Twitter no image is displayed in the Twitter Card.

I use the Jekyll-seo-tag but when adding a image tag in the Front Matter it doesn't work and I get a 404 instead of the post when I go to the corresponding URL.

What I tried :

```
---
layout: post
title:  "lorem ispum - Week 22 of 2018"
subtitle: "An inside look at ...."
date:   2018-06-04 17:00:00
authors: [ John Doe ]
icon: icon-calendar
tags:
 - core-weekly
image: /assets/images/2017/04/...
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

**The `image` tag should not be in the last position in the Front Matter.**

When I put it in the middle it works, I get the image on Twitter card.

See below:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "lorem ispum - Week 22 of 2018"
subtitle: "An inside look at ...."
date:   2018-06-04 17:00:00
authors: [ John Doe ]
image: /assets/images/2017/04/...
icon: icon-calendar
tags:
 - core-weekly
---
```

Comment: Your conclusion is misleading. It doesn't matter if you have the `image` key at the very end of your front matter. The issue is probably in the indentation as YAML is sensitive to indentation. I advise you to recheck and edit your answer

Comment: I tried this and it made no difference for me